# Evaluation of a limit using another

Tags: calculus, limits, alternative-proof, limits-without-lhopital

- Here's the question :

> Let $f : R\to R$ be a real function. The function $f$ is derivable and there exists $n \in N$ and $p \in R$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^nf(x) = p$, and there exists $lim_{x \to \infty} (x^{n+1}.f(x))$ , then evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x^{n+1}f'(x))$

- What I did :

The limit which equals $p$ can be solved using L' Hopital's Rule (once or many time depending on $f(x)$ and $p$)

So applying L' Hopital's Rule once to the term in the limit will yield the same value of the limit.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^{-n}} = p$$

Apply L-H Rule here

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{-nx^{-(n+1)}} = p$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty } f'(x)x^{n+1} = -np$$

> Now I am looking for alternate ways to do this question

So please mention how would you do this problem; Thanks...

Comment: Is the assumption really that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{n+1}f(x)$ exists? Or should it be $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{n+1}f'(x)$?

Comment: No, it is correct

Comment: @Milten its correct, it should be $f(x)$

Comment: Really? If $\lim x^nf(x)=p$, then $\lim x^{n+1}f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(p)\infty$ follows immediately.

Comment: @Milten yes you are right, I didn't think through the counter example so well........But I would still appreciate another approach

Comment: @Milten I will edit the question to remove the counter example the discrepancy

Comment: ................